# M2Doc error <---Couldn't find the 'getText(EClassifier=Model)' service

Tags: m2doc

I was using m2doc programmatically, and this is my code.

```java
final URI templateURI = URI.createFileURI(templateName+"."+M2DocUtils.DOCX_EXTENSION_FILE); 
final URI modelURI = URI.createFileURI(modelName);
        
// can be empty, if you are using a Generation use GenconfUtils.getOptions(generation)
final Map<String, String> options = new HashMap<>();
List<Exception> exceptions = new ArrayList<>();
                
final ResourceSet resourceSetForModels = M2DocUtils.createResourceSetForModels(exceptions , "key", new ResourceSetImpl(), options);
//resourceSetForModels.getResource(modelURI, true);
final Resource r = resourceSetForModels.getResource(modelURI, true);
System.out.println(r.getContents());
final EObject value = r.getContents().get(0);

// if you are using a Generation, use GenconfUtils.getQueryEnvironment(resourceSetForModels, generation)
final IQueryEnvironment queryEnvironment = M2DocUtils.getQueryEnvironment(resourceSetForModels, templateURI, options); // delegate to IServicesConfigurator
                
final IClassProvider classProvider =  new ClassProvider(this.getClass().getClassLoader()); // use M2DocPlugin.getClassProvider() when running inside Eclipse
final Monitor monitor = new BasicMonitor.Printing(System.out);
try (DocumentTemplate template = M2DocUtils.parse(resourceSetForModels.getURIConverter(), templateURI, queryEnvironment, classProvider, monitor)) {
            
        // validate
    final ValidationMessageLevel validationLevel = M2DocUtils.validate(template, queryEnvironment, monitor);
    if (validationLevel != ValidationMessageLevel.OK) {
        final URI validationResulURI = URI.createFileURI(templateName+"-validation."+M2DocUtils.DOCX_EXTENSION_FILE); // some place to serialize the result of the validation
                     M2DocUtils.serializeValidatedDocumentTemplate(resourceSetForModels.getURIConverter(), template, validationResulURI);}
        
    //generate
    final Map<String, Object> variables = new HashMap<>(); // your variables and values
    variables.put("self", value);
    final URI outputURI = URI.createFileURI(templateName+"-result."+M2DocUtils.DOCX_EXTENSION_FILE); // some place to serialize the result of the generation
    M2DocUtils.generate(template, queryEnvironment, variables, resourceSetForModels, outputURI, monitor);
}finally {
        
        M2DocUtils.cleanResourceSetForModels("key", resourceSetForModels);
}
```

And when I ran the program, the validation file was created, and it shows lots of errors. The errors were like this: `<---Couldn't find the 'getText(EClassifier=Model)' service`. They appeared everywhere I used the service `getText()`.

When I use the same template and the same uml file to generate document by using the m2doc plugin in eclipse, it went alright.

I wonder if my query environment setting was wrong.
Thank you if you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

M2DocUtils.parse() initialize the IQueryEnvironment with services and nsURIs imported in the template. So you should not need to add anything.

If you are running inside Eclipse you should use:

```
final IClassProvider classProvider = M2DocPlugin.getClassProvider()
```

It should help loading your service Class (it use OSGi to load classes from bundles).

You can also check if any TemplateValidationMessage are present with more details:

```
DocumentTemplate.getBody().getValidationMessages()
```

At this point either the UML metamodel is not registered or it's your service Class (more likely).

You can register the UML EPackage and see if it helps:

```
queryEnvironment.registerEPackage(UMLPackage.eINSTANCE)
```

You can also try to register your service class:

```
final Set<IService> s = ServiceUtils.getServices(queryEnvironment, SomeServiceClass.class);
ServiceUtils.registerServices(queryEnvironment, s);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. First, I tried use the `M2DocPlugin.getClassProvider(`), but I cannot find M2DocPlugin in m2doc, so I cannot import it. Second, I used `template.getBody().getValidationMessages(`), but it returned an empty list. And I have a further question for you: what is a UMLPackage? Could you please give me a more specific instruction about registerEPackage? Thanks again.

Comment: You need to add org.obeonetwork.m2doc.ide to your MANIFEST.MF. But only do this if you are running inside Eclipse not from a Java main for instance. The UMLPackage is a class representing the UML metamodel. see https://git.eclipse.org/c/uml2/org.eclipse.uml2.git/tree/plugins/org.eclipse.uml2.uml/src/org/eclipse/uml2/uml/UMLPackage.java. You will need to add org.eclipse.uml2.uml to your MANIFEST.MF file to be able to reference that class.